# How can I create an owner dropdown menu?

Tags: rally

How can I create a Dropdown menu where I can filer for owners instead of releases or iterations?

Comment: Fabian, are you asking a question about creating an App using Rally's App SDK or a general question about using the Rally product? If the latter, it would be best to create a support case by clicking on the 'Contact Support' on the bottom of any page in Rally. Also, what do you mean by 'filer'?

Comment: The question is about using the App SDK. I'm trying to extend the "Story Board"-App so that I can limit the displayed user stories by iteration and owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dropdown that allows you to show possible owners by using the [Attribute Dropdown](http://www.rallydev.com/help/dropdown-components#Attribute%20Dropdown).

If you need additional help the provided code example can be copied into an App tab so you can see it in action.